# calling the function from <div> attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-callback

For example, i have the next code:

```
var sale =  {};
sale.MainContent = function(p) {
    alert("this handler is main-content");
}
```

and also I have the next html div:

```
<div id="content-data" data-handler="MainContent">{"name":"John"}</div>
```

I try do do next things - parsing the content of div in jquery, like this:

```
var cd=$("#content-data");
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(cd.text());
```

And when i get the attribute fo data-handler:

```
var hname=cd.attr("data-handler");
```

So, the next step - call the function with name hname = 'MainContent' in sale object like this(?):

```
sale.hname(obj);
```

How i can call the function name in variable?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this -

```
sale[hname](obj);
```

Comment: And how look the call of function, if a want to send whole name in attribute?

Comment: data-handler="sale.MainContent"? [h](obj)?